# passing variable from a page to an already opened page with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a first page "main.php" with a button opening a pop-up "pop.php" with a form where i can check different options. After choosing the different option and when pressing "ok", is it possible with js or jquery to pass the result of the "pop.php" form to a field in "main.php" without reloading it?
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.** With JavaScript it is possible, with jQuery it's easier.

jQuery on **`pop.php`**

```
<script>    
jQuery(function($){
    // when your popup form submits this will be called
    $('form').submit(function(event){
        // this stops the form from submitting
        event.preventDefault();
        // this sends the form data to a JS function on main.php
        window.parent.popup_data_process($(this).serialize());
        // this closes this window because we don't need it anymore
        window.close();
    });
});  
</script>
```

JS on **`main.php`**

```
<script>
// this function is the receiver which will process your form data
function popup_data_process(serializedData)
{
    // this displays the data to your console
    console.log(serializedData);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent window using the window.parent property.  and call any global level function you wish

```
var popUp = window.open("pop.php");
```

inside pop.php

```
if(!!window.parent){
  window.parent.someFunction(dataToPadd);
}
```